# Checkbox checked not working based on condition in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this checkbox when `user.IsActive` is `0` still the checkbox is checked

```
<input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="user.IsActive" (change)="user.IsActive = $event.target.checked ? 1: 0" [checked]="user.IsActive == 1 || user.IsActive=='1' ? true : false">
```

i have used this condition `[checked]="user.IsActive == 1 || user.IsActive=='1' ? true : false"`

but it's not working.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Can you try removing the `[(ngModel)]` binding as you already bind by `(change)` and `[checked]`?

Answer (score 1):

Jay Swaminarayan
Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="user.IsActive = !user.IsActive" [checked]="user.IsActive">
```